# Should I refactor with hobo?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a created a [userdriven gallery](http://www.kunstpladsen.dk) with Ruby on Rails.The site is using a few plugins to create friendly links, permissions, pageless pagniation etc. The application controllers and views has gotton quite complex and I find it difficult and very time consuming to work with. So I thought about rebuilding the app with [hobo](http://hobocentral.net/), as it includes all the user and permission logics and another template system. However I am affraid that I will be to limited, or maybe not win anything becasue I will loss a lot of time hacking hobo. I am planning to add frinedships and personal messing to my website. Could this be to compelx for hobo? Does hobo use jquery?

Best regards.
Asbjørn Morell.

Answer (score 1):

Hobo is not that complex, however you would need to study documentation which takes some time. But, in the long-run any refactoring such as Hobo could help, if the code is currently getting unmaintainable.

JQuery can be used in any sytsem as it is independent of script frameworks etc. AFAIK,

Comment: I have allready gone through all documentation on hobocentral. Just wanted to confirm if this was a bad or good idea.. How good is the hobo templating system?

Comment: sorry, i don't know hobo templating system that well, maybe someone other will help

Answer (score 1):

No one can tell you if Hobo will help your specific program.

That said, I have been using Hobo for a while and I have found it to be very effective.  It handles a good part of the standard rails logic every site needs (such as routes).  The dryml system has been useful in my work as well, reducing the size and complexity of my views.

If your code is becoming unmaintainable and you feel a refractor is necessary, you could definitely do worse than Hobo.

Comment: Without knowing his application, there's no way for SO to help you with the question of how much you'll need to hack Hobo (other than to share their own experiences), but when I evaluated it for a straightforward app, I was pretty impressed.

The only definite negative I ever perceived was that I'd be hitching my wagon to hobo long-term, and might delay (or outright prevent) me from moving to newer versions of Ruby/Rails down the stetch. Most similar Rails-based frameworks are now completely unmaintained and out of date, so I'd fear dealing with the same fate for hobo at some point.

Answer (score 0):

i have been building a few hobo apps and they work rock solid, problem is dryml is quite peculiar and you must learn and do a lot of test and try, but in the end it allways comes along quite nicely. i recommend you start quickly with hobo and you will end up faster..!!